# How to bind event on sap.m.MessageBox in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using [this MessageBox demo](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessageBoxInitialFocus/preview) in Explored.  How to bind event on buttons: MessageBox.Action.YES/"Custom Button" ?

In [MessageBox.show api](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageBox.html#.show), I only found `onClose` parameters.

Comment: I think https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/samples Dialog would be a better option to define custom button or controls.

Comment: Thanks @hdereli, I've already solve my problem by using `sap.m.Dialog`. Just curious if there is no way to bind event in messagebox, what's the point of using custom button in it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example that shows how to handle the OK, CANCEL, and a "Custom Button" within the MessageBox.confirm method:

```js
    MessageBox.confirm(sText, {
        title: sTitle,
        initialFocus: sap.m.MessageBox.Action.CANCEL,
        onClose: function(sButton) {
            if (sButton === MessageBox.Action.OK) {
                // Action for the OK button
            } else if (sButton === MessageBox.Action.CANCEL) {
                // Action for the CANCEL button
            } else if (sButton === "Custom Button") { // Fixed the missing quote here
                // Action for the custom button
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

your link points to a SAP internal page which is not reachable for people outside of SAP, please be sure to post links which are accessible from the internet.

In this [Explored Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/events) you can see there are events for the button in the footer.

Comment: Sorry , I've redirected it to [https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com). And the event you provide is for `sap.m.Dialog`, not `sap.m.MessageBox`? So there is no way to bind event for MessageBox?

Answer (score -1):

Below is example to bind this inside Message Box
only small change from above code

```
MessageBox.confirm(sText, {
    title : sTitle,
    initialFocus : sap.m.MessageBox.Action.CANCEL,
    onClose : function(sButton) {
        if (sButton === MessageBox.Action.OK) {
            // Do something
        } elseif (sButton === MessageBox.Action.CANCEL) {
            // Do something
        } elseif (sButton === "Custom Button) {
           // Do something
        };
    }.bind(this)
});
```